# How to extract information from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to create a Login page and validating the incoming details against the database. But my code isn't able to cross check data from the database. Below is the output result I'm getting from the application:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcjTo.png)

Following is the code I'm working on

**Default.aspx Code**:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="LogIn.aspx.cs" Inherits="LogIn" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
<!-- Login & Register -->
    <section>
    <div class="pageintro">
        <div class="pageintro-bg">
            <img src="images/bg-page_01.jpg" alt="About Us"/>
        </div>
        <div class="pageintro-body">
            <h1 class="pageintro-title">Login</h1>
            <nav class="pageintro-breadcumb">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

            <!-- Login -->
            <div class="col-lg-6 ">
                <div class="au-form-body p-r-lg-15 p-r-xl-15">
                    <h2 class="au-form-title form-title-border">Login</h2>
                    <fieldset class="m-t-40">

                            <div class="form-group au-form require">
                                <label>Email address</label>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group au-form require">
                                <label>Password</label>
                                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtpwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group au-form">
                                <asp:Button ID="loginbtn" runat="server" Text="Log In" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                                <asp:Label ID="loginmessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Button ID="logoutbtn" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Log Out" Visible="False" />
                                <div class="form-forgot w-100 m-t-10">
                                    <a href="forgetpassword.aspx">Lost your password?</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Login -->
```

**Default.aspx.cs Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class LogIn : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TEAFAMILY;Initial Catalog=Bolsen;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
    sqlCon.Open();
    Type cstype = this.GetType();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader rdr;
    String strSql1 = "SELECT * FROM Customers ";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql1, sqlCon);
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read() == true)
    {
        if (txtemail.Text == (string)rdr["cEmail"] &&
            txtpwd.Text == (string)rdr["cPassword"])
        {
            Session["sFlag"] = "T"; // sFlag = "T" means user has logged in
            Session["sName"] = rdr["Firstname"];
            Session["sEmail"] = rdr["cEmail"];
            Session["sAddress"] = rdr["cCompanyAddress"];
            Session["sEmail"] = rdr["cEmail"];
            logoutbtn.Visible = true;
            sqlCon.Close();
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        } //end of if
    } //end of while loop
    // userid and password not matched, hence login unsuccessful
    Session["sFlag"] = "F";
    Session["sName"] = "";
    Session["sUserId"] = "";
    loginmessage.Text = "Error in login - Please login again   ";

    sqlCon.Close();
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    logoutbtn.Visible = false;
    Session["sFlag"] = "L"; // L for logout
    Session["sName"] = "";
    Session["sUserId"] = "";
    Session["sOrderNo"] = "";
    txtemail.Text = "";
    txtpwd.Text = "";
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

}
}
```

Would someone point out what's wrong with the code?

Comment: @SahilSharma: please do not add chatty material when editing questions - we remove this, not add it back in. There is no need to add how much help is appreciated, especially if the question author did not write it themselves. It can be assumed.

Comment: I often post this advice: _Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Comment: There’s a reason to add such context; when 90% of the question contains code, editor won’t allow me to edit and submit it back without adding some context. Otherwise I’ll agree on the same with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to fetch all the records from the database just to check a single result. Change your `Button1_Click` event code to this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = txtemail.Text;
        string password = txtpwd.Text;
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TEAFAMILY;Initial Catalog=Bolsen;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"))
        {
            string query = "SELECT Top(1) * FROM Customers WHERE cEmail = @Username and cPassword = @Password";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
            sqlCon.Open();

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                Session["sFlag"] = "T"; // sFlag = "T" means user has logged in
                Session["sName"] = rdr["Firstname"];
                Session["sEmail"] = rdr["cEmail"];
                Session["sAddress"] = rdr["cCompanyAddress"];
                Session["sEmail"] = rdr["cEmail"];
                logoutbtn.Visible = true;
                sqlCon.Close();
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Session["sFlag"] = "F";
                Session["sName"] = "";
                Session["sUserId"] = "";
                loginmessage.Text = "Error in login - Please login again   ";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey there im getting an error that says rdr does not exist in the current context is t here something i should add in?

Comment: Updated the answer to fetch only single record with `SqlDataReader`